# How do I assign this value to a global variable in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to assign a value that's being received from a socket (TCP/IP) to a variable, so I can use it in a label in a form.
I'm asking here because I've been searching and trying for hours and can't find anything.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Exemys
{
        static byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
        static Socket sck;
        [STAThread]
        public static void Conectar(/*string[] args*/)
        {
            sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IPEndPoint localEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.34.230"), 5202);
            try
            {
                sck.Connect(localEndpoint);
                Console.WriteLine("Exemys connected!\r\n");
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.Write("Unable to connect to Exemys\r\n");
                Conectar(/*args*/);
            }
        while (true)
        {
            Buffer = new byte[sck.SendBufferSize];
            int bytesRead = sck.Receive(Buffer);
            byte[] formatted = new byte[bytesRead];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytesRead; i++)
            {
                formatted[i] = Buffer[i];
            }
            string mensaje = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(formatted);
            Console.Write(mensaje + "\r\n");
            
        }
    }       
}
}
```

This code is written in a class, and the Form is in other place.
The value that I need to assign is `mensaje`, so I can see it in a Text Box in the Form.

Comment: `"the Form is in other place"` - What other place?  How is this code related to the form?

Comment: @David sorry if I express myself poorly, the form is in the same project. I meant that this code isn´t in the Form´s code.

Comment: This code implies that this is the entirety of a Console Application.  Is it?  How does the form relate to that?

Comment: @David Yes, this is the entirety a Console Application. I just added a form, wich contains a Text Box.
What I need is to see the value `mensaje` received from socket in that Text Box.

Comment: You could access the form statically via Form.property=value or (better) have an instance form.property=value

Answer (score 0):

First of all global variables smells like a bad design. Anyway, it seems like you are giving an example of a **ConsoleApplication** but you have maybe a **Windows Form Application**? Obviously you can not run a Form from a Console Application, so just convert everything to a Windows Forms Application to start with.

Anyway, after you have a Form working, you will probably could change your code so that **Conectar()**, that we in fact we can give a better name like **ConnectAndGetMessage()**, to actually return the message. Then you call that method from your Form, maybe on the Load handler.

Briefly, you could do something like this:

```
class Exemys {

    public static string ConnectAndGetMessage() {
        // Here your code! ;)
        return mensaje;
    }
}

class FormWithTextbox {

    private void FormWithLabel_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        Textbox1.Text = Exemys.ConnectAndGetMessage();
    }
}
```

Please note that this is not the best solution because you should inject the Exemys as a dependency instead, anyway, that will be for a later improvement.

Another thing to point out about your code, but you will probably get to know quickly is that you are not exiting the while loop, so you will probably end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this and tell you if this was useful to me!
In reference to the while loop, I configured it like that, because I need to constantly read the data that's being received, I couldn't find anything else!

Comment: In that case, you should connect, and then try to get the data from a while loop outside the Exemys class, so you will able to return the things that you receive. Well, hope that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried the code you gave me, but it didn't work. The value still doesn't appear in the text box. Thank you anyways!